# Make a command to remove NetworkManager connections

Tags: scripting, executable, networkmanager

I’m working in a manufacturing company (small one) and one of our clients required a test using a Linux (Ubuntu) computer, we are testing some wi-fi modules. the test is simple. beforehand: Powering up the units (loaded with test FW) will create an access point where the SSID is the MAC Address of said unit and there is no password

The test is as follows:

1. Connect the laptop to the wi-fi access point
2. Inside a terminal use command `sh mfg.sh` (file provided by them) which has `sudo` inside so it will require password the first time used
3. The script will do everything and just put in text PASSED or FAILED
4. Power down the unit, if you want to test another one keep terminal open

Test is pretty simple right?, the issue comes with the access points (AP), for starters, there is something about the Wi-Fi module on the laptop that it doesn’t see the next AP but it keeps seeing the old one (even after powering down the unit), so we have to do a manual service restart using `sudo service network-manager restart` after the restart we now see the AP.

Then another issue, every unit has a different SSID (different MAC Address) so every time you connect to a new one, a file is born in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` and after 50 or so files the connection to a new AP is slow, to revert that I delete all the previous AP using `sudo rm -r /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*`

Ok so here comes the question. Since the low-level operators are only familiarized with windows computers, is there a way to encapsulate this commands into a Icon type executable? like, just double click it, it opens terminal do his thing and closes, also it would be the best to not be ask for password to use `sudo`. I tried doble clicking the `mfg.sh` file but it only oppened on editor.

I’m pretty proficient in computers but this is my first approach with Linux environments, every comment and suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unix systems do not care about file extensions, well some applications do, but the OS does not. Also you do not want the extension (What will you do if you rewrite in python?).

Unix systems care about the file being executable (So does MS-Windows, but by default all files are executable. Even that dodgy file you downloaded from viruses are us.) To set a file to executable you need to do `chmod +x filename` `chmod` is change mode (permisions) `+x` means add eXecute.

Next configure `sudo` to not need password for the required commands. See `man sudo`.